# Cannot read response from AngularJS $resource JSONP get from Yahoo Finance

Tags: resources, jsonp, angularjs, yahoo-finance

I am able to get stock prices from Google Finance using Angular JS $resource with JSONP.  This is shown here:  http://jsfiddle.net/8zVxH/1/

I need historical prices, which Google does not provide, but Yahoo does.  I modified the above jsfiddle to this:  http://jsfiddle.net/curt00/BqtzB/

Here's the code:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

function AppCtrl($scope, $resource) {

    var yqlURL="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";

    var dataFormat="&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

    var symbol = 'GOOG';

    var startDate = '2012-12-05';
    var endDate = '2012-12-06';

    var historical_query = yqlURL+"select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22"+ symbol +"%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%22"+ startDate +"%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%22"+ endDate +"%22"+ dataFormat;

    $scope.yahooFinance = $resource(historical_query, 
                                 {callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'},
                                 {get: {method:'JSONP', isArray: false}});

    $scope.indexResult = $scope.yahooFinance.get();

}
```

​
It generates an error message in the browser console:

GET http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22GOOG%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222012-12-05%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222012-12-06%22&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys?callback=angular.callbacks._0 400 (Bad Request)

Does anybody know how to get this to work?

I know that Jquery's getJSON can be used with this Yahoo query, but supposedly AngularJS' $resource is faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Use angular's $http service.

With function jsonp from angular service $http, it is quite easy to achieve.

**Service**

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
app.factory('service', function($q, $http) {

    return {
        getHistoricalData: function(symbol, start, end) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var format = '&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
            var query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "' + symbol + '" and startDate = "' + start + '" and endDate = "' + end + '"';
            var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + format;

            $http.jsonp(url).success(function(json) {
                var quotes = json.query.results.quote;
                // filter + format quotes here if you want
                deferred.resolve(quotes);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
function Ctrl($scope, service) {
    $scope.symbol = "GOOG";
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.startDate = '2012-12-05';
    $scope.endDate = '2012-12-06';

    $scope.getData = function() {
        $scope.items = [];

        var promise = service.getHistoricalData($scope.symbol, $scope.startDate, $scope.endDate);

        promise.then(function(data) {
            $scope.items = data;
        });
    };
    $scope.getData();
}​
```

I've created a working example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/7bNAd/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It was helpful.  However, it returns NULL. This is confirmed by entering the url into a browser.  Also, the url that starts with 'ichart.yahoo.com' downloads prices for every historical date, instead of just the dates between from and to.  I had to make a few changes, which can be seen here:  http://jsfiddle.net/curt00/XY89Y/1/.  Your "getHistoricalData : function" and "$log.info" caused errors.  Are those Javascript commands?

Comment: It was a part of a custom (angular) service

Comment: I made progress with your help. Now, I am stumped in trying to access the data inside the histData object after it is returned to where I call the getHistoricalData function.  Please see the code at my posting at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979324/cannot-access-elements-in-object-returned-by-javascript-function-in-angularjs

Comment: Edited my answer. I've created a jsfiddle for you. It is a working example: [http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/7bNAd/](http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/7bNAd/)

Comment: I tried putting your new code into mine.  But I'm stuck with this error in the console:  TypeError: Cannot call method 'getHistoricalData' of undefined.  This is being triggered by "var promise = service.getHistoricalData(..."  How do I get past this?

Comment: Are you using the latest code from my jsFiddle? Did you try it in your own jdFiddle

Comment: Yes, I copied your code.  I did not try my own jsFiddle as I can see it works in yours.  I have _angular.app.js (which has "function AppCtrl($scope..."), controller.stock.js (controller for stock.html) and index.html (which has "angular.module('app', ['filers'..."  I tried putting your code that starts with "app.factory('service'..." into each of the three files, but I still get the undefined error.  Is it just me, or is AngularJS very difficult to work with?

Comment: I suggest you place it first in my javascript file and break it up once it works.

Answer (score 1):

As a angularjs noob, this fixed it for me.

Changed my `jsonp` **from:**

```
JSON_CALLBACK({"term_jg_1":{"query":"Julia.......
```

**to**

```
angular.callbacks._0({"term_jg_1":{"query":"Julia...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody for providing suggestions.

@asgoth's suggestion looks slick but I was not able to get it to work on my AngularJS web app.

I replaced $resource with $http.jsonp and now it works.  Example:

```
var query = 'select * from csv where url=\'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=' + symbol + '&a=' + (date.month - 1) + '&b=' + date.day + '&c=' + date.year + '&d=' + (date.month - 1) + '&e=' + date.day + '&f=' + date.year + '&g=d&ignore=.csv\'';
var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + fixedEncodeURIComponent(query) + '&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

    $http.jsonp(url, {timeout: 30000}).success(function(json) {
        var result = json.query.results.row;
        //  process result
    }
```